# Simplest working example of extracting Type names from given path of package

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm new to golang AST package and related go tools like astutils. At the moment I'm a bit stucked in understanding the Stringer example and modifying it for my own purpose.

https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/cmd/stringer/stringer.go

Is there an working example of simply extract a list of all defined type names in a package path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've came up with this example of a program that prints all (top-level) type names. Parse the directory, get the package, and walk it.

```
fs := token.NewFileSet()
pkgs, err := parser.ParseDir(fs, dir, nil, 0)
// Check err.
pkg, ok := pkgs["pkgname"]
// Check ok.
ast.Walk(VisitorFunc(FindTypes), pkg)
```

Where `VisitorFunc` and `FindTypes` are defined as

```
type VisitorFunc func(n ast.Node) ast.Visitor

func (f VisitorFunc) Visit(n ast.Node) ast.Visitor { return f(n) }

func FindTypes(n ast.Node) ast.Visitor {
    switch n := n.(type) {
    case *ast.Package:
        return VisitorFunc(FindTypes)
    case *ast.File:
        return VisitorFunc(FindTypes)
    case *ast.GenDecl:
        if n.Tok == token.TYPE {
            return VisitorFunc(FindTypes)
        }
    case *ast.TypeSpec:
        fmt.Println(n.Name.Name)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Full code on Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/Rk_zmrmD0k (won't work there since the FS operations are disallowed).

---

**EDIT:** Here is a version that works on the Playground, by Ivan Black in the comments: https://play.golang.org/p/yLV6-asPas

Comment: What about doing this against the standard library? Is the only opportunity to follow env GOROOT path down to the src folder under the compiler? I'am looking for a way to lookup what type is returned from functions in the standard library, and I think this is the only solution??

Comment: Hello, my friend. I patched your playground code. It works like a charme now https://play.golang.org/p/yLV6-asPas. Feel free to use `/tmp` directory on the playground.

Comment: @IvanBlack Thanks, added to the answer!